# How to place two divs side by side using css

Tags: css, html

I have two divs on my page and I want to display them side by side. I have tried using `float:left` and `display:inline-block`, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help Please? This is a what my page looks like [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/6/)

Comment: Take out `<p><h3>OR</h3></p>`... [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ATdkE/7/)

Comment: to add to @Ruddy's comment, alternatively you could wrap that line (with `OR`) in a div and float it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<p>` or `<h3>` and set it `inline-block` too  , reset `white-space` for `#maincontent`  and its inner content:

http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/15/

```
div#login, div#register, #maincontent > h3 {
    white-space:normal;/* reset to normal */
    display:inline-block;
}
div#login, div#register {
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f8f8f8);
    border: 1px solid #d0d2d5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebfc2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 212px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#maincontent {
    white-space:nowrap;/* keep all inline element on one single line */
    text-align:center;/* no need of obsolete attribute in HTML markup :) */
}
```

you can add some margin and change vertical-align http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/17/

Comment: This works! and thanks for the style too, really appreciate you explaining what each line is doing. @GCyrillus

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them within a parent div that has fixed margins. i.e. margins not set to "auto".

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "OR" inside the header tag. Header tags are display block by default, so they are overwriting your float left. You can also change the header tag to float: left;

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to write tags inside `<p></p>` you should get rid of `<p>` and directly write

```
<h3>OR</h3>
```

Give style to

```
h3{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/10/)

Answer (score 0):

First the invalid HTML,

You cant have a block level element inside the `p` tag, so please remove the `p` tags that surround the `h3` tags

Second, make the display of the `h3` with text **OR** as `inline-block`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/14/

You may have to add some more styles

Comment: I had no idea you couldn't do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IE supports inline-block, but only for elements that are natively inline.
Use

```
float:left
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ATdkE/18/